# Cross Join is creating a Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, join, cross-join

I have three tables, I need to make a `CROSS JOIN` between them to display the IDs and names of the products and the stores that sell them, here is an example of how now

`TABLE_PRODUCT`

```
ID_PRODUCT  |   NAME_PRODUCT  
1           |   Addidas Super Star
2           |   Calvin Klein BAG
```

`TABLE_STORE`

```
ID_STORE |   NAME_STORE 
1        |   ThE 98
2        |   C&A
```

`TABLE_PROD_STOR`

```
ID_STORE  |  ID_PROD
1         |  1
2         |  2
```

And I need the result in the format:

```
ID STORE  |  STORE  | ID PRODUCT |       PRODUCT      |
1         |  ThE 98 | 1          | Addidas Super Star |
2         |  C&A    | 2          | CALVIN KLEIN HAT   |
```

My biggest problem is that when I do the `CROSS JOIN`, the names are repeated twice each. What is the solution?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`, not `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Cross Join means take # of records from each table and multiply them so 2*2*2 = 8 records.  (take each record in product and pair it with each reocrd in store and then take the result and pair it with each reocrd in prod_store). Inner join means take records from each table that relate on some key values (like ID_Product and ID_Store)  since 1= 1 and 2=2 you'd only get 2 records using an inner join.  [This blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) does a good job of visually depicting the join types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
y.ID_STORE  ,
y.NAME_STORE store ,
x.ID_PRODUCT,
x.NAME_PRODUCT  product
from
TABLE_PRODUCT x inner join
TABLE_STORE y 
   on x.ID_PRODUCT =y.ID_STORE 
inner join TABLE_PROD_STOR z
   on x.ID_PRODUCT =z.ID_STORE
```